# Android: why use intent.putExtra() method?

Tags: android, android-intent

This is a real noob question I'm sure, but I am finding it quite perplexing.

Why an earth would you want to ever use intent.putExtra method to share information between classes in Android?

Let me explain. I am making my first Android app following the instructions from the developers guide (I am already at a moderate level with Java) and I am using some code that looks like this:

//Class field

```
//key holds string????? not fully understanding this...

public static final String EXTRA_MESSAGE = "self.anon.myfirstapp.MESSAGE";



//this method is activated by a button being pressed

public void sendMessage(View view) {

    Intent intent = new Intent(this,DisplayMessageActivity.class);
    EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_message);
    String message = editText.getText().toString();
    //puts string message inside the string EXTRA_MESSAGE - why????
    intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, message);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

OK firstly I want to point out I see what is happening and for the most part how it works (am just confused by the field declaration = "myClassPath" why?)...

BUT....

Surely it would be easier just to have a static field called:

```
public static String message;
```

then my method would look like this:

```
public void sendMessage(View view) {

    Intent intent = new Intent(this,DisplayMessageActivity.class);
    EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_message);
    message = editText.getText().toString();
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

Then when my class DisplayMessageActivity needs the string message he just calls for:

String message = myClass.message;

That seems so much more straight forward. What is with the creation of the new string EXTRA_MESSAGE which just seems to hold the string message and why send it with the intent when my other class can access this info directly anyway -- and what does the field declaration with the "self.anon.myfirstapp.MESSAGE" mean? I can find no such folder or path leading to anything.

Comment: Have you tried using your method? That would mean your myClass would need to be static, which I don't think is possible

Comment: Edited it Kevin... better?

Comment: Comilpiled and ran exactly the same way when I did it my way as when I did it the more complicated way that the tutorial suggested.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As someone else stated there are often situations (such as a screen rotate) in which the android system destroys and restarts the app - so all variable data is lost. It would only work consistently the way you suggest if your data is hard coded as a final variable. That is not the only reason for using intents though.

The great thing with using an intent to pass information is that you can use the intent not just to communicate with sub-activities within your own application but to any activity installed on that android system. For example you may want to launch an intent which starts the phone application and include as an extra the number that you want to call.

Perhaps a better question than yours though is *"why would you not use intents to pass information?"* The `intent.putExtra()` method allows you a convenient flexible and straight forward method to pass as much information as you like in a safe and secure way to any other activity.

Answer (score 0):

intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, message);

works like a key value pair, when you want to retrieve the information from the intent you can simply do `intent.get<type>Extra` and get said information, in this case, `intent.getStringExtra("self.redway.myfirstapp.MESSAGE')`. its simply the key to retrieve the information, it does not have to be your entire classpath.

it could just as easily be `intent.putExtra("message",message)`.

They are helpful when passing information that you don't necessarily want to reveal to another class but you do want it to be able to get that information in another manner from what i have found.

Comment: Ok so the self.redway.myfirstapp.MESSSAGE is simply a kind of index which represents the actual string? Yes? (I hope I'm with you so far).. but where is it stored? Is it stored within the intent itself then? It is clearly no longer the String variable message which would no longer exist at the methods close... still confused. Again I would stress I am a real noob. Thanks.

Comment: As far as i understand it is contained in the intent, and is passed along with the intent to the activity that you start with it. I dont believe that it is stored anywhere else. and yes, it's an index, basically `putExtra(KEY,VALUE)`

Comment: That does make sense to me - so I'm grateful for that :) I'm still confused as to why not send the information over in the same way you would in java i.e. via a getMessage() method or simply making the field public and referencing it directly as I put in the code above... is there some other benefit to putting the string within the intent (for example can it be accessed when building XML Views or something specefic to Android like that?) or is it as another person has commented because the string may not be held within the class in a predictable fashion?

Comment: I dont think you can make an object of an activity, which is what you would have to do to access a variable like that from another activity.  Also, whenever you do a  screen orientation change or leave an activity it loses all of its current values, as Illegal Argument stated.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that is incorrect because I have compiled and run the above code and it works perfectly! And of course you can access a variable from another class! You don't need to instantiate the class at all! The code above as I say works perfectly as is, in fact in the demo code utilized in the tutorial it has one class pass the other the actual index varialbe EXTRA_MESSAGE. So it clearly is not a problem with losing the string or any of that. I am thinking now perhaps they have just done it this way because it is good practice and it demonstrates how the putExtra() method works.

Answer (score 0):

**message = myClass.message** It is not always certain that this will retain its value especially when it extends Android framework classes like Activity. When your activity is recreated(change of screen orientation) then **message** can lose its current value and be assigned a default value. **myClass.message** would work if message was a static field or else you would need to provide getter and setter methods for object of the **Activity Class**. Well creating objects of activity class is unheard of in my experience.